# How to access model property inside java script function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display prompt for user to make easy for him to copy some text which would be concatenation of `Model` properties.

If I do this:

```
   function CopyToClipboard() {        
        window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", @Model.Id);
    }
```

it works I get:

[image]

but If I want to pass property of type `String`, like this:

```
   function CopyToClipboard() {        
        window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", @Model.FirstName);
    }
```

there is no prompt.

Comment: I'm not familiar with razor but try putting quotes around @Model.FirstName: window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", "@Model.FirstName");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 2 can be inserted without quotes, and is converted to a string automagically

```
function CopyToClipboard() {        
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", 2);
}
```

any other string would be a syntax error

```
function CopyToClipboard() {        
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", Yoda); // error
}
```

because it needs to be quoted

```
function CopyToClipboard() {        
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", "@Model.FirstName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function CopyToClipboard() {        
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", '@Model.FirstName');
}
```

The javascript code has to be inside the html receiving the model.